# HLSL - Sampling a render target texture always return black color

Tags: c++, directx-11, hlsl, pixel-shader

Okay, first of all, I'm really new to DirectX11 and this is actually my first project using it. I'm also relatively new to Computer Graphics in general so I might have some concepts wrong although, for this particular case, I do not think so. My code is based on the [RasterTek tutorials](http://rastertek.com/tutdx11.html).

In trying to implement a shader shader, I need to render the scene to a 2D texture and then perform a gaussian blur on the resulting image.
That part seems to be working fine as when using the Visual Studio graphics debugger the output seems to be what I expect.

However, after having having done all post processing, I render a quad to the backbuffer using a simple shader that uses the final output of the blur as a resource. This always gives me a black screen. When I debug my pixel shader with the VS graphics debugger, it seem like the Sample(texture, uv) method always returns (0,0,0,1) when trying to sample that texture.

The pixel shader works fine if I use a different texture, like some normal map or whatever, as a resource, just not when using any of the rendertargets from the previous passes. 
The behaviour is particularly weird because the actual blur shader works fine when using any of the rendertargets as a resource.

I know I cannot use a rendertarget as both input and output but I think I have that covered since I call OMSetRenderTargets so I can render to the backbuffer.

Here's the step by step of my implementation:

1. Set Render Targets
2. Clear them
3. Clear Depth buffer
4. Render scene to texture
5. Turn off Z buffer
6. Render to quad
7. Perform horizontal blur
8. Perform vertical blur
9. Set back buffer as render target
10. Clear back buffer
11. Render final output to quad
12. Turn z buffer on
13. Present back buffer

Here is the shader for the quad:

```
Texture2D shaderTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState SampleType : register(s0);
struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

float4 main(PixelInputType input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);
}
```

Here's the relevant c++ code

This is how I set the render targets

```
void DeferredBuffers::SetRenderTargets(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, bool activeRTs[BUFFER_COUNT]){

    vector<ID3D11RenderTargetView*> rts = vector<ID3D11RenderTargetView*>();
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_COUNT; ++i){
        if (activeRTs[i]){
            rts.push_back(m_renderTargetViewArray[i]);          
        }
    }

    deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(rts.size(), &rts[0], m_depthStencilView);

    // Set the viewport.
    deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &m_viewport);
}
```

I use a ping pong approach with the Render Targets for the blur.
I render the scene to a MainTarget and depth information to the depthMap. The first pass performs an horizontal blur onto a third target (horizontalBlurred) and then I use that one as input for the vertical blur which renders back to the mainTarget and to the finalTarget. It's a loop because on the vertical pass I'm supposed to blend the PS output with what's on the finalTarget. I left that code (and some other stuff) out as it's not relevant.
The m_Fullscreen is the quad.

```
bool activeRenderTargets[4] = { true, true, false, false };

// Set the render buffers to be the render target.
m_ShaderManager->getDeferredBuffers()->SetRenderTargets(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext(), activeRenderTargets);
// Clear the render buffers.
m_ShaderManager->getDeferredBuffers()->ClearRenderTargets(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext(), 0.25f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
m_ShaderManager->getDeferredBuffers()->ClearDepthStencil(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext());


// Render the scene to the render buffers.
RenderSceneToTexture();

// Get the matrices.
m_D3D->GetWorldMatrix(worldMatrix);
m_Camera->GetBaseViewMatrix(baseViewMatrix);
m_D3D->GetOrthoMatrix(projectionMatrix);

// Turn off the Z buffer to begin all 2D rendering.
m_D3D->TurnZBufferOff();

// Put the full screen ortho window vertex and index buffers on the graphics pipeline to prepare them for drawing.
m_FullScreenWindow->Render(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext()); 

ID3D11ShaderResourceView* mainTarget = m_ShaderManager->getDeferredBuffers()->GetShaderResourceView(0);
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* horizontalBlurred = m_ShaderManager->getDeferredBuffers()->GetShaderResourceView(2);
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* depthMap = m_ShaderManager->getDeferredBuffers()->GetShaderResourceView(1);
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* finalTarget = m_ShaderManager->getDeferredBuffers()->GetShaderResourceView(3);
activeRenderTargets[1] = false; //depth map is never a render target again

for (int i = 0; i < numBlurs; ++i){

    activeRenderTargets[0] = false; //main target is resource in this pass
    activeRenderTargets[2] = true; //horizontal blurred target
    activeRenderTargets[3] = false; //unbind final target
    m_ShaderManager->getDeferredBuffers()->SetRenderTargets(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext(), activeRenderTargets);
    m_ShaderManager->RenderScreenSpaceSSS_HorizontalBlur(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext(), m_FullScreenWindow->GetIndexCount(), worldMatrix, baseViewMatrix, projectionMatrix, mainTarget, depthMap);

    activeRenderTargets[0] = true; //rendering to main target
    activeRenderTargets[2] = false; //horizontal blurred is resource
    activeRenderTargets[3] = true; //rendering to final target
    m_ShaderManager->getDeferredBuffers()->SetRenderTargets(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext(), activeRenderTargets);
    m_ShaderManager->RenderScreenSpaceSSS_VerticalBlur(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext(), m_FullScreenWindow->GetIndexCount(), worldMatrix, baseViewMatrix, projectionMatrix, horizontalBlurred, depthMap);

}

m_D3D->SetBackBufferRenderTarget();
m_D3D->BeginScene(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
// Reset the viewport back to the original.
m_D3D->ResetViewport();


m_ShaderManager->RenderTextureShader(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext(), m_FullScreenWindow->GetIndexCount(), worldMatrix, baseViewMatrix, projectionMatrix, depthMap);

m_D3D->TurnZBufferOn();
m_D3D->EndScene();
```

And, finally, here are 3 [screenshots](http://1drv.ms/1PfabNa) from my graphics log.
They show rendering the scene onto the mainTarget, a verticalPass which takes as input the horizontalBlurred resource and finally, rendering onto the backBuffer, which is what's failing. You can see the resource bound to the shader and how the output is just a black screen. I purposedly set the background as red to find out if it was sampling with wrong coordinates, but nope.

So, has anyone ever experienced something like this? What could be the cause of this bug?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT**: The Render_SOMETHING_SOMETHING_shader methods handle binding all the resources, setting the shaders, draw calls etc etc. If necessary I can post them here, but I don't think it's that relevant.

Comment: Order of assignment is also important,if  you try to assign a ShaderResourceView whereas it's still bound as RenderTarget, the runtime will preserve the render target and force the shader resource to null.
It will not set your ShaderResourceView and automatically reset RenderTarget.

Also enable debug layer and check if you don't have this message in your ouput window:D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources: Resource being set to PS shader resource slot 0 is still bound on output! Forcing to NULL. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #7: DEVICE_PSSETSHADERRESOURCES_HAZARD]

Comment: By order of assignment, what exactly do you mean? that first you need to set the render targets and ony then the resources? I do that already.
In any case I have no such warning and I do not think that my problem is the resource being set to null. Looking the the graphics log, if I check the DeviceContext state, the pixel shader shows it has the proper resource bound.